# How can I run the following command with curly braces in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I a bash script I have the following

```
CMD="{ head -n1 $DATE.$FROMSTRAT.new && egrep -i \"$SYMS\" $DATE.$FROMSTRAT.new; } > $DATE.$TOSTRAT.new" 
echo "Running $CMD"                                                                                     
`$CMD`
```

When I call the script

```
Running { head -n1 inputFile.new && egrep -i "X|Y" inputFile.new; } > outputFile.new
script.sh: line 17: {: command not found
```

But when I run `{ head -n1 inputFile.new && egrep -i "X|Y" inputFile.new; } > outputFile.new` on the command line it works fine.

I try to escape the `{` with no success, how can I do this ?

Comment: If it's a string, you will need to evaluate it with `eval` or by passing it to `bash -c "..."`. But in general that is not a good idea, error-prone, accidently clobbering files with weird input, debugging etc. Why the indirection?

Comment: Consider whether your script is complicated enough that you would be better off rewriting the entire thing in a better programming language (the obvious choices are Perl and Python).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you use a variable on the command line like that, it will be split to words, but that happens after syntactical items like `{` (or `if`) are parsed. So, if you want that, you'll have to use `eval`

```
CMD="{ echo blah ; echo bleh; } > output"
eval "$CMD"
# output contains "blah" and "bleh"
```

Though note `eval` will run everything in the variable in the current shell, including assignments to variables (changing `IFS` may have funny effects for the rest of the script, say). You could run it in a separate shell with `bash -c "$CMD"` to mitigate at least the variable assignment issue.

Also note that the backticks are used to capture the output of a command, and use it on the command line, so this would run the output of `$CMD` also as a command:

```
$ CMD="echo foo"
$ `$CMD`
-bash: foo: command not found
```

If you're redirecting the output to a file, it won't matter, but you most likely also don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
function exec_cmd() {
    printf "+ %s \n\n" "$1"
    bash -c "$1" || exit 1
}

exec_cmd '{ head -n1 inputFile.new && egrep -i "X|Y" inputFile.new; } > outputFile.new'
```

Then you don't have to worry about escaping the strings.
Note about `bash -c <command>` usage, the next argument after `<command>` is used as `$0` (the script's "name" from inside the script), and subsequent arguments become the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.).